# How to get the ajax response and append it to an html?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I used the autocomplete function of jquery and what I want is instead of displaying all the results in a textbox I want to display all the data in a selectbox. But I don't know how. Here's a bit of my code:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="filter_product_name" id="filter_product_name" value="" />
    <select name="parent_selection">
        <option value="0">Not Set</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

...the ajax process...

```
 $('input[name=\'filter_product_name\']').autocomplete({
        delay: 500,
        source: function(request, response) {
           $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete_product&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_product_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request.term),                                                                                                                                                        
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(json) {

                    response($.map(json, function(item) {

                        $('select[name=\'parent_selection\']').html('<option value="'+item.product_id+'">'+item.product_name+'</option>');

                    }));

                }
           });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't really think that's how the plugin works, it returns the html in the response() function to the input, and returning a select to an input doesn't really do anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys,
After reading some codes in the web I found a solution for my answer.

Here's what I did:

```
$('input[name=\'filter_product_name\']').autocomplete({
    delay: 500,
    source: function(request, response) {
       $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete_product&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_product_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request.term),                                                                                                                                                        
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {

            },
            success: function(json) {

                $html = '';

                response($.map(json, function(item) {
                    console.log(item);
                    $html += '<option value="'+item.product_id+'">'+item.product_name+'</option>';
                }));

                $('select[name=\'parent_selection\']').html($html);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

            }
       });
    }
});
```

And it returns the ajax autocomplete result in my selectbox.

Thanks for your suggestions. I will take that as a reference for my future studies. Thanks again.

Comment: as suggested in my answer, you don't need to use escape character `\'`, use double quetes `"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

With Input always use `.val();`

```
$('input[name=\'parent_selection\']').val('<option value="'+item.product_id+'">'+item.product_name+'</option>');
```

But it is pointless to append HTML into input, so better use

```
$('input[name=\'parent_selection\']').after().html('<option value="'+item.product_id+'">'+item.product_name+'</option>');
```

With updated quesion comes updated answer. You can use `append()`

```
$('select[name=\'parent_selection\']').append('<option value="'+item.product_id+'">'+item.product_name+'</option>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put select options inside `select` tag and your jquery selector is showing that you are selecting an `input` element.

Hence you need to change this :

```
$('input[name=\'parent_selection\']').html('<option value="'
 +item.product_id+'">'+item.product_name+'</option>');
```

to this :

```
$('select[name="parent_selection"]').append('<option value="'
 +item.product_id+'">'+item.product_name+'</option>');
```

And use `.append()` instead of `.html()`, because `.html()` will replace what is inside `select` tag and this results into only one `option` tag at the end of loop. And `.append()` will keep on adding `option` to your `select` tag and you will get all options at the end of loop.

Also you don't need to use escape character `\'` for name, you can use double quotes `"` instead.